# Python can't decode the given encoded bytes string

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, encoding, decoding

I'm trying to decode a byte string after detecting the type of encoding it has gone through.

The string is:

```
\xa1\xb6\xb0\xb5\xd2\xb9\xa1\xb7\x00\x02\x00`\xeb\x03h\x10\xeb\x03\x03\x12+\x00\n\xfe\n\x03
```

The detected encoding is `big5`, when I try to decode that using string.decode('big5') it throws the below error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'big5' codec can't decode bytes in position 12-13: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Need some help as to how to solve this issue?

Comment: The _detected_ encoding? How did you detect it? The error message says that it can not decode the bytes at position 12, 13, which are `\xeb\x03`. This makes sense: The big5 encoding stores byte pairs. The first byte in such a pair can take values in the ranges [0xa1, 0xc6] and [0xc9, 0xf9]. The second byte can take values in the ranges [0x40, 0x7e], [0xa1, 0xfe]. The second byte of your pair is 0x03, which is clearly not in the allowed range.
Edit: Mh, some more of your pairs are out of range, maybe I need to check that again.

Comment: Where does the string come from? Decoding succeeds if I use just the first 12 bytes, but I can't judge if the characters make sense (a triangle and two Chinese characters).

Comment: Some bytes in your string are null (`\x00`). Maybe the string is null-terminated? Then the string would only consist of the first 8 bytes, which can be decoded successfully.